Azure Synapse: How to get notebook magic command %pip to work in a pipeline
When running %pip install in my Synapse notebook manually, it works as intended, without any problems.
However, when I try to run that same notebook in a pipeline, I get:
{
    "errorCode": "6002",
    "message": "MagicUsageError: %pip magic command is disabled.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": <my_notebook_name>,
    "details": []
}

I have looked at these two posts:
Why magic command doesn't work when running pipeline?
Synapse : Execute the Magic Command (%run) Notebook from Pipeline
But these are both only concerned with the %run command, not %pip
The solution to both of those posts is to add an absolute path, which makes sense in the context of a %run command, but I'm not sure how to translate adding an absolute path to %pip? Or if there is something else that can make this work?

I have received same ERROR when using the %pip command and running pipeline.

I have tried the below approach:
I have created a requirements.txt file for the dependencies that need to be installed.
For example I have created a dependency for splink==1.0.3
I have uploaded the requirements.txt
Go to Manage tab > Spark Pool



Now I ran the notebook to verify the if the version of the dependency is correct?

Next, I ran the pipeline.
Results:


You can replace 'pip' with the following code:
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "boto3"])
subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "pyarrow==15.0.0"])


I am able to install packages using:
!pip install xyz
The problem is sometimes the python interpreter needs to be restarted without restarting the pool which will necessitate the need to reinstall the packages.  The magic command will do this automatically but won't work in a pipeline.  I was able to get around this by setting the notebook to retry upon failure in the pipeline.
The first time the notebook runs it pip installs the packages and then fails upon import.  On the retry the python kernel is restarted and the imports work.
